# Using jquery to get element's position relative to viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, viewport, offset

What's the proper way to get the position of an element on the page relative to the viewport (rather than the document). [`jQuery.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function seemed promising:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the
>   coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative
>   to the document.

But that's relative to the document. Is there an equivalent method that returns offsets relative to the viewport?

Comment: NOTE: See @Igor G's answer...

Comment: To DA, you should really set Igor G's answer as accepted, it's a life saver!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look into the Dimensions plugin, specifically `scrollTop()`/`scrollLeft()`.  Information can be found at http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop.

Comment: I didn't want to use another plugin, but  $(window).scrollTop() is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: The dimensions plugin is now a part of jQuery core. The ViewPort plugin can also be useful: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Answer (score 292):

The easiest way to determine the size and position of an element is to call its
[getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method. This method returns element positions in viewport coordinates. It expects no arguments and returns an object with
properties *left, right, top*, and *bottom*. The left and top properties give the X and Y
coordinates of the upper-left corner of the element and the right and bottom properties
give the coordinates of the lower-right corner.

`element.getBoundingClientRect(); // Get position in viewport coordinates`

Supported everywhere.

Comment: This seemed great at first but it does not account for a user zooming on Mobile Safari 7.

Comment: Not supported by latest firefox `getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Comment: @user007 I confirm that it IS supported by lastest firefox.

Comment: This answer just saved my @ss and taught me something new. Should be accepted answer

Comment: Great answer, and to make it jquery simply do it this way : `$('#myElement')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top` (or any other position)

Comment: thank you so much!! i didn't really realize this and was using getComputedStyle...which gave me auto in some circumstances :)

Comment: Why doesn't jQuery use this so that when we're calculating a position we get the desired output, which is what this answer gives!!!!

Comment: Note that CSS `transform`s do affect these element bounds!

Answer (score 40):

Here are two functions to get the page height and the scroll amounts (x,y) without the use of the (bloated) dimensions plugin:

```
// getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
function getPageScroll() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
      xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
    return new Array(xScroll,yScroll)
}

// Adapted from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
function getPageHeight() {
    var windowHeight
    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
      windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
      windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return windowHeight
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use the "self" property instead of window in this case?

Comment: @Denis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638887/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-window

Answer (score 31):

[`jQuery.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) needs to be combined with [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [`scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) as shown in this diagram:

[image: viewport scroll and element offset]

Demo:

```js
function getViewportOffset($e) {
  var $window = $(window),
    scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft(),
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
    offset = $e.offset(),
    rect1 = { x1: scrollLeft, y1: scrollTop, x2: scrollLeft + $window.width(), y2: scrollTop + $window.height() },
    rect2 = { x1: offset.left, y1: offset.top, x2: offset.left + $e.width(), y2: offset.top + $e.height() };
  return {
    left: offset.left - scrollLeft,
    top: offset.top - scrollTop,
    insideViewport: rect1.x1 < rect2.x2 && rect1.x2 > rect2.x1 && rect1.y1 < rect2.y2 && rect1.y2 > rect2.y1
  };
}
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
  var viewportOffset = getViewportOffset($("#element"));
  $("#log").text("left: " + viewportOffset.left + ", top: " + viewportOffset.top + ", insideViewport: " + viewportOffset.insideViewport);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 1600px; height: 2048px; background-color: #CCCCCC; }
#element { width: 384px; height: 384px; margin-top: 1088px; margin-left: 768px; background-color: #99CCFF; }
#log { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; font: medium monospace; background-color: #EEE8AA; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- scroll right and bottom to locate the blue square -->
<div id="element"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: this worked great for me, but I was using this to determine if a tooltip was going out-of-bounds, so I have modified to include bottom and right values: http://jsfiddle.net/EY6Rk/21/

Comment: This is the absolutely, in any case, correct answer. All the others have issues depending on mouse/scroll delta configuration, browsers, obj location, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that calculates the current position of an element within the viewport:

```
/**
 * Calculates the position of a given element within the viewport
 *
 * @param {string} obj jQuery object of the dom element to be monitored
 * @return {array} An array containing both X and Y positions as a number
 * ranging from 0 (under/right of viewport) to 1 (above/left of viewport)
 */
function visibility(obj) {
    var winw = jQuery(window).width(), winh = jQuery(window).height(),
        elw = obj.width(), elh = obj.height(),
        o = obj[0].getBoundingClientRect(),
        x1 = o.left - winw, x2 = o.left + elw,
        y1 = o.top - winh, y2 = o.top + elh;

    return [
        Math.max(0, Math.min((0 - x1) / (x2 - x1), 1)),
        Math.max(0, Math.min((0 - y1) / (y2 - y1), 1))
    ];
}
```

The return values are calculated like this:

[image]

Usage:

```
visibility($('#example'));  // returns [0.3742887830933581, 0.6103752759381899]
```

Demo:

```js
function visibility(obj) {var winw = jQuery(window).width(),winh = jQuery(window).height(),elw = obj.width(),
    elh = obj.height(), o = obj[0].getBoundingClientRect(),x1 = o.left - winw, x2 = o.left + elw, y1 = o.top - winh, y2 = o.top + elh; return [Math.max(0, Math.min((0 - x1) / (x2 - x1), 1)),Math.max(0, Math.min((0 - y1) / (y2 - y1), 1))];
}
setInterval(function() {
  res = visibility($('#block'));
  $('#x').text(Math.round(res[0] * 100) + '%');
  $('#y').text(Math.round(res[1] * 100) + '%');
}, 100);
```

```css
#block { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; background: yellow; top: 50%; left: 50%; position: relative;
} #container { background: #EFF0F1; height: 950px; width: 1800px; margin-top: -40%; margin-left: -40%; overflow: scroll; position: relative;
} #res { position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 2; font-family: Verdana; background: #c0c0c0; line-height: .1em; padding: 0 .5em; font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res">
  <p>X: <span id="x"></span></p>
  <p>Y: <span id="y"></span></p>
</div>
<div id="container"><div id="block"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer by cballou was no longer working in Firefox as of Jan. 2014. Specifically, `if (self.pageYOffset)` didn't trigger if the client had scrolled right, but not down - because `0` is a falsey number. This went undetected for a while because Firefox supported `document.body.scrollLeft`/`Top`, but this is no longer working for me (on Firefox 26.0).

Here's my modified solution:

```js
var getPageScroll = function(document_el, window_el) {
  var xScroll = 0, yScroll = 0;
  if (window_el.pageYOffset !== undefined) {
    yScroll = window_el.pageYOffset;
    xScroll = window_el.pageXOffset;
  } else if (document_el.documentElement !== undefined && document_el.documentElement.scrollTop) {
    yScroll = document_el.documentElement.scrollTop;
    xScroll = document_el.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  } else if (document_el.body !== undefined) {// all other Explorers
    yScroll = document_el.body.scrollTop;
    xScroll = document_el.body.scrollLeft;
  }
  return [xScroll,yScroll];
};
```

Tested and working in FF26, Chrome 31, IE11. Almost certainly works on older versions of all of them.