# What's the difference between self and window?

Tags: javascript, window

I have a JavaScript that deals with with detection whether the page is in frames or not. I used top.frames[] etc. and everything works fine.

In this script I noticed that I can use "window" or "self" interchangeably and everything still works. Is "window" same as "self" when used in HTML page?

Comment: When using Web Workers self and window are not the same thing. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219775/global-variable-in-web-worker][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219775/global-variable-in-web-worker

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From *Javascript: The Definitive Guide*:

> The Window object defines a number of
>   properties and methods that allow you
>   to manipulate the web browser window. 
>   It also defines properties that refer
>   to other important objects, such as
>   the `document` property for the
>   Document object.  Finally, the Window
>   object has two self-referential
>   properties, `window` and `self`.  You
>   can use either global variable to
>   refer directly to the Window object.

In short, both `window` and `self` are references to the Window object, which is the global object of client-side javascript.

Comment: Except necro-bug if FF6.0, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7769187/139361, `window` and `self` should be identical. Anyone knows any other bugs? 

---------------------------------------
I must add that using `self` is confusing to most javascript developers, so use `window` instead.

Answer (score 28):

`self` is a **read-only** property that can be more flexible than, and sometimes used in favor of, the `window` directly. This is because `self`'s reference changes depending on the operating context (unlike `window.self`, which only exists if `window` exists). It's also great for comparisons, as others have mentioned.

For example, if you use `self` inside a Web Worker (which lives in its own background thread), `self` will actually reference `WorkerGlobalScope.self`. However, if you use `self` in a normal browser context, `self` will simply return a reference to `Window.self` (the one that has `document`, `addEventListener()`, and all the other stuff you're used to seeing).

**TL;DR while the `.self` in `window.self` will not exist if `window` doesn't exist, using `self` on its own will point to `Window.self` in a traditional window/browser context, or `WorkerGlobalScope.self` in a web worker context.**

As usual, MDN has a great writeup on this subject [in their JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self). `:)`

---

*Side note:* The usage of `self` here should not be confused with the common JS pattern of declaring a local variable: `var self = this` to maintain a reference to a context after switching.

You can read more about that here: [Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations).

Comment: window.self is not read-only. Try it. You can change the property just by assigning it a new value. So can someone please explain to me why all the docs say that it is read-only?

Answer (score 13):

Here's the explanation and example from [the MDN page for `window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self):

```
if (window.parent.frames[0] != window.self) {
   // this window is not the first frame in the list
}
```

> **window.self** is almost always used in comparisons like in the example above, which finds out if the current window is the first subframe in the parent frameset.

Given that nobody is using framesets these days, I think it's okay to consider that there are no useful cases for `self`. Also, at least in Firefox, testing against `window` instead of `window.self` is equivalent.

Comment: For code that needs to run independent of a browser, it seems better to use `self`, i.e. headless execution.

Comment: @nilskp, that's interesting, but I did not understand you. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Dan, `window` is only present in a GUI (browser). Not all Javascript code runs in a browser. In those cases, `self` will still work, but `window` will not.

Comment: @nilskp, I think the topic is about difference between `window` and `window.self`. If there is no `window`, `self` would automatically disappear. I found nothing about magic `self` variable in node.js. On the other side, PhanomJS emulates true window object. Do you know any other non-browser environments where javascript executes, where `self` is provided?

Comment: @Dan, Rhino (Java implementation).

Comment: Given that `window === window.self` is `true` (in FF and Chrome, at least), why not just use `window.parent.frames[0] !== window`?

Answer (score 5):

`window` and `self` both refer to the global object of the current web page.

For more info have a look at http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserinspecific

Answer (score 1):

### What do the keywords "self" and "window" represent in JavaScript?

**2022 Update** - I added this explanation below with more complete information affecting HTML5 DOM, etc. in modern browsers.

1. For starters, `self` and `window` are just keywords, and are names of members in the Window Object interface. They are keywords that reference the same window object that gets created when you visit a web page in the browser. A Window Object then gets created as part of the HTML DOM accessed by scripts like JavaScript with these two keywords assigned. This Window Object is then commonly accessed via the more popular `window` keyword. However, the two keywords are allowed as defined in the interface definition shown below:

```
interface Window {
  readonly attribute WindowProxy window;
  readonly attribute WindowProxy self;
  ...
}
```

2. `self` and `window` are just JavaScript keywords that point to the same Window Object. However, notice above they do not point back to the parent itself, but are actually pointers to a *WindowProxy* object. The WindowProxy Object is a wrapper around the Window Object shown above, and exists in one instance for every web page Window you visit in the web browser context. Note that **only one WindowProxy Object exists per tab**. However, as you surf to different web pages, a new Window Object must be created inside the mother WindowProxy. This allows the browser to manage all Window Objects it creates via its proxy object without having to lose each window browsing context and view. The *WindowProxy* is both a security and memory feature, allowing access to each underlying window instance each page view creates, while protecting the wrapped *Window Object* child inside it.
   When the window gets created, assigning `self` and `window` keywords to its proxy allows both to access the parent proxy instead of a specific Window Object instance, and let the WindowProxy route any calls to the current window context.
3. Besides security and context of referencing the *WindowProxy*, this routing to the Window Object via a wrapper was especially important in the old "frame" HTML days when there might be many window contexts holding other parent or child window object in HTML4 frames. This was especially important in cross-domain issues in frames 20 years ago! That is the next reason for `self` vs `window`. The keyword `self` (as in `window.self`) used to have another important meaning, and was actually used to help determine what frame you were referencing. It was used to represent a specific window context and reference the top or controlling web page frame that held other frames. `window.self` might or might not be the same as `window.parent.frame[0]`, for example! Those "frame days" are basically dead due to security issues accessing windows in frames, so were deprecated after HTML4.2 was replaced with HTML5, which only supports the `iframe` now. However, its important to realize `self` had a prior use beyond its primary reference back to the global scope of a web page's top Window Object, as used today.
4. Next, notice that the following is true in JavaScript when inside a typical window or web page browsing context:

```
self === window.self === window
```

So why use `self` today if you have `window`?

It turns out that `window`, like `self`, always points to the *WindowProxy* object, which then points back again to the window itself again and the current Window Object instance in the browser tab. It's `self-referential`, yet can ONLY point to itself.
But `self`, when used inside other non-window contexts, can refer to its global scope or parent, including **Web Worker API Objects**, which are parallel threads that run alongside the *Window Object* and which have their own *non-window scope*. When you create a *Web Worker* object in JavaScript, and use self to access it, you are referencing the top object of the *Web Worker* called `WorkerGlobalScope`. However, self can also reference different flavors of the Web Worker global scope when they are other types like `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope`, `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`, etc. These all exist OUTSIDE the *Window Object*, and have their own global scope like `window`.

So `self` now has a larger purpose as an alias to whatever `Global Scope` or parent object is being accessed!

No one online seems to explain any of this...so I had to patch together this concept from lots of references. But the overall theme is that these keywords in JavaScript don't always *self-reference* the same objects! Each was added to overlap each other (and thus confuse people), but then supersede their primary purpose and be used for extended purposes that might appear.

So if you see `self` and `window`, understand in a typical window global scope, they are the same. These key words are both designed to reference the Window Object via the WindowProxy wrapper quickly and securely. But **I recommend you ALWAYS use `window`** and avoid `self`, unless you are dealing with Web Workers.