# What is self.moveBy and why doesn't it work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I found the `self.moveBy` function [here](http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Earthquake.phtml).

Somehow the code doesn't seem to work on Chrome, although `self.moveBy` does exist on Chrome!

What exactly is `self.moveBy`, and why doesn't it work on Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a javascript security setting that is disabled by default
will be disabled by default in firefox too (some late Nightly version)
including:

```
window.moveBy
window.moveTo
window.resizeTo
window.resizeBy
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as window.moveBy, and moves the current window by a specified amount.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.moveBy

See also, [What's the difference between self and window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638887/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-window)

I don't think you can get it to work in chrome, and I can see why they would want to disable it, although it is fun ;-)