# Global variable in Web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am using this Web worker which has a Global variable declared in it. Can I access the same (Global variable in worker 1) in the newly spawned web worker(worker 2)?

When I've tried using jQuery in web worker, I get error "window is not defined". Is there any way to use jQuery in a `Web Worker`?

```
importScripts('jquery-latest.js');

function fetch_ajax(url) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
    postMessage(response);  


    }
  });
}

fetch_ajax('test.txt');
```

Comment: You seem to have asked two questions here. StackOverflow questions should be kept separate. I'm pretty sure the jQuery question is already answered, so it's probably best just to remove that part from your question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Web Workers don't have a `window` object.

To access global state, use `self` instead, code that will work on both the main thread and the worker thread.

But note that you still won't be able to access or manipulate the parent `DOM` (e.g. get `window.jQuery` via `self.jQuery`).

While the main thread window `self` points to the Window object, in worker threads `self` points to a separate `WorkerGlobalScope` object.

Comment: Tnx I practically tested and found I am unable to access a variable in worker1 in worker2. And also unable to use jQuery as there is no access to window object. Instead, I used native XHR and returned the response successfully...

Comment: And it's a **good** thing. Communication with workers is via messages (`PostMessage` method and `onmessage` event). Access to DOM or some shared variables would result in lots of nasty errors...

Comment: My understanding is that the global scope in each web worker, and in the main thread (the web page), are all separate, but that in each case, they can be accessed via the `self` object. In the main thread, `self` is a synonym for `window`. Is this your understanding as well, or did you mean something else?

Comment: @MichaelScheper The `self` property of a global object basically returns `this` (perhaps not literally, but conceptually). So, `window.self`returns `window`, and `self` inside a Web Worker returns the global object of the worker (whatever that's called).

Answer (score 23):

Based on @buley tip, I did it:

```
var window = self;

importScripts(/* dependencies here */);

/* my code */
```

In my case I was trying to use the ES6-Promise lib: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise#readme

Comment: This "tip" is somewhat risky.For some different purpose (sharing code), I am using the test `typeof window !== 'undefined'` to check if I am in a web worker, or in the main client-side JavaScript. It wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: @allezl'OM It might be better to check for window.document.