# Unexpected use of 'self' no-restricted-globals React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to write a Service Worker for my PWA app, caugth this error. I used Google/Mozilla samples for service workers, but, anyway.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'test-cache';
var urlsToCache = [
    '/'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function (cache) {
                console.log('Opened cache');
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
    );
});
```

Comment: what does `self` in `self.addEventListener` refer to?

Comment: Service worker object, i think.

Comment: I used Mozilla PWA sample. But i don't understand why not even this code don't work

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Following the sample here : https://engineering.musefind.com/build-your-first-progressive-web-app-with-react-8e1449c575cd

Answer (score 35):

You can explicitly remove `self` from the [no-restricted-globals](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals) rule or simply disable the rule for the line containing `self` using `eslint-disable-line` or `eslint-disable-next-line`:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) { /* eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals */
...
```

Or

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals */
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `window.self` instead of `self`.

Comment: by using `window.self` the goes away. but the `addEventListener` which is doing install does not actually install the service worker

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is so highly rated. The question is about accessing the global object in a ServiceWorker. Both ServiceWorkers and WebWorkers do not have `window` objects so this suggestion will not work. Accessing the global object using `self` is the correct thing to do. The rule should be disabled @Fraction points out below.

Comment: downvoted answer. self and window.self are not the same thing on nor-browser environments e.g. serviceworker. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638982/6196679

Comment: I downvoted this answer. As previously stated above, workers dont have a window shortcut for the global scope.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is not correct and should not be rated so high.

Comment: UpVoted cause it solved my problem. 
although, to be fair, my problem *was not* the question's problem (working with a serviceworker) but rather a browser enviroment related problem. So take that into account. Since that's why so many people want to downvote it.

Either way, solved my problem, so upvote.