# What's the difference between window, self, parent, and top in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I know what `window` is, and also `self` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638887/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-window), but what about `parent` and `top`, and how do they relate to `window` and `self`?  What do `parent` and `top` point to?

From anchor tags, it seems like `parent` means the `window` that is iframing the current `window`, and `top` references the topmost `window`, for example if the `parent` is also being iframed inside an `iframe`.  Is this `true`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what they do. (Not just for iframes but also for normal frames)

Comment: @Bergi: OK.  Just wanted to know because I didn't see anything on Stack Overflow for `parent` and `top`.

Comment: I found one now :-) See also MDN for [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) and [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top)

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for directing me to a source for which I can use.  Hopefully it helps others in the future.