# tracking scrolling offset of a fixed div from top of window

Tags: jquery

So i have a long scrolling 1page website with a fixed navigation bar.

With this navigation bar I would like to track its `.offset().top` so I may add or remove classes based on the offset from the top of the window.

[Live code link](http://www.designobvio.us/para)

**Example** (this is my logic but i cannot make the jQuery alert even work.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var elem = $('.navigation');
  var topValue = offset.top;
  if (topValue > 400) {
    alert(topValue);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). Instead of specifying an offset, you use the elements on your page to trigger a callback whenever they come into view:

```
$(function () {
  $("#map").waypoint(function () {
    alert("Scrolled to #map");
  });
});
```

**Edit:**

But to properly answer your question, your navigation will always be in the same position because `position: fixed` positions your element relative to the viewport, not the page. If you want to do this without Waypoints, just check the `body` tag’s `scrollTop`:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var offset = $("body").scrollTop();
    if (offset > 400)
      alert("Scrolled to 400");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using `offset.top`, but you have no `offset` variable declared, meaning that the `.top` is not returning anything.

It seems that You've looked at the jQuery documentation for the [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), but haven't understood/read the example properly.

At the documentation, they are initializing a variable:

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
```

And then extracting the `.top` and `.left` values:

```
alert(" coordinates: ( " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + " ) ");
```

---

Looking at the web-page from your link, you don't need a very extensive script to check how much did the user scroll. This small function gives you what you need:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/a9G6e/) Example!

```
// getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
function getPageScroll() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
      xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
    return new Array(xScroll,yScroll)
}
```

More reading about this can be found at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567387/352449).