# How to get the current position of an element relative to the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to get the current position of an element relative to the window,
 not document

offset get the current position of an element relative to the document

Comment: you could use Element.getBoundingClientRect()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13930064/5695475 Explains how you can do this using `offset()` `scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()`

Comment: @dading84 Thanks a lot it's worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute position of an element on the screen using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929972/absolute-position-of-an-element-on-the-screen-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate where the element is positioned relative to the top edge of the viewport, you can use a combination of:

- `getClientBoundingRect()` (to determine the position of the element within the document); and
- `window.scrollY` (to determine the vertical scroll position of the window).

Then, simply subtract the second value from the first:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

function alertCurrentPosition() {
    var windowVerticalScroll = window.scrollY;
    window.alert('The top of the red square is ' + (divRect.top - windowVerticalScroll) + ' pixels below the top of the viewport');
}

button.addEventListener('click', alertCurrentPosition, false);
```

```css
body {
height: 1200px;
}

button {
position: fixed;
top: 6px;
left: 6px;
}

div {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button>Scroll the Viewport and Click Me</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle. 
I think you'll get the answer.
Here is the

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/mk4q332q/
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked with me well

```
var offset = $("selector").offset();
var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
var posX = offset.left - $(window).scrollLeft();
```

I got the answer from here [stackoverflow.com/a/13930064/5695475](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13930064/5695475)